# AnimatedVisibility causing layout shifts in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I'm facing an issue with `AnimatedVisibility` in `Jetpack Compose`.
When an element becomes visible using `AnimatedVisibility`, it causes layout shifts and affects the positions of other components on the screen.

This is because `AnimatedVisibility` doesn't seem to reserve any space for the hidden element, leading to unexpected layout changes upon its appearance.

```
var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Column {
    Button(onClick = { isVisible = !isVisible }) {
        Text(text = "Toggle Visibility")
    }
 
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = isVisible,
    content = {
        Card(
             modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp) // Example height for the content
        ) {
            Text(text = "This content appears upon button click")
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**:
The button initially appears at the top of the screen. When clicked, the card element becomes visible using `AnimatedVisibility`. However, this causes the button to shift downwards, as the card doesn't seem to reserve any space while hidden. This behavior is undesirable, as it disrupts the layout flow and creates a jarring visual experience.

**Questions**:

- How can I prevent layout shifts when using `AnimatedVisibility`?
- Are there ways to instruct `AnimatedVisibility` to reserve space for the hidden content, even before it becomes visible?
- Are there alternative approaches to achieve conditional visibility with minimal layout impact?

Comment: First of all AnimatedVisibility Removed And Add Element so you must keep in mind that behaviour

Comment: bro i did not understand a word @ChiragThummar

Comment: Animate visibility do transitions from gone to visible, if you want to do animation from invisible to visible, maybe you should use animateFloatAsState for alpha, also, AnimateVisibility receives modifier, so you can set size of it.

Comment: that is a good solution. if you want you can answer my question so i can accept your answer @МилошКојадиновић

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, animate visibility goes from gone to visible, if you want animation from visible to invisible, just use alpha like this:

```
Column {
    var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Button(onClick = { isVisible = !isVisible }) {
        Text(text = "Toggle Visibility")
    }

    val alpha by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (isVisible) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000),
        label = ""
    )


    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .alpha(alpha)
            .height(100.dp) // Example height for the content
    ) {
        Text(text = "This content appears upon button click")
    }
}
```

If you want to keep Animate visibility with better animation, as you know height of card, you can set height of AnimateVisibility container:

```
 AnimatedVisibility(
    modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp),
    visible = isVisible,
    content = {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp) // Example height for the content
        ) {
            Text(text = "This content appears upon button click")
        }
    }
)
```